# PHP Possible ways to write an if

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm wondering if there is any way to make this code shorter. I'm using 2 `if` statements and I'm looking to only use one. The things is `$user` is the session and if you check if `$user->userId` exists on the same line, the code will error when no session exists. Caused by requesting the `userId` from an object that does not exist. That's pretty logical but now is there any solution?

```
if ($user != null) {
  if ($user->userId == 1) {
    ..
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [the `&&` operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php):

```
if ($user && $user->userId == 1) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Waw, then I did something wrong when I tried to do the same before. Anyway thanks alot.

Comment: @user2103237 Just to clarify, `if ($user ...` checks is equivalent to `if ($user == true ...`, so, most likely, this is fine for you, but beware that `0`, `false`, `''`, `'0'`, etc all do *not* equal `true`, but `1`, `true`, `'false'`, `'1'`, etc all *do* equal `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many sentences as you want, as long as they are properly built, in this case:

```
if (($user != null) && ($user->userId == 1)) {
```

or you could simply:

```
if ($user && ($user->userId == 1)) {
```

if ($user) just checks if the variable is set, or if it is not null.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `&&` operator. It means and

```
if ($user && $user->userId == 1) {
    // do some things
}
```

You may also want to look into the `||` operator, it means or.

The `&&` operator will return true ONLY if the two predicates return true.

The `||` operator will return true as long as one of the predicates return true.